# any looping mechanism in IBM conversation?

Tags: ibm-watson, watson-conversation

There is often a situation where multiple entities are recognized and you may want to loop through all recognized entities and create a response that includes each of them. e.g. through the elements of an array while creating the response.

I tried using the "argument ? command1 : command 2" and nesting further arguments in command 1 to create a sort of looping but this way is very error prone.

Any easy way of doing it?

Answer (score 0):

You can control this from context and SDK throught API.
When you send message to Conversation you get intents and entities array. You can loop it throught your code and send or concatenate response.

If you can share workspace I can help

Comment: Thanks for your answer..but im afraid i can't share my workspace

Comment: @devenrana you can create a sample

Answer (score 0):

If you have Multiple Entity of same type then you can use @EntityName.values to store all the values of that enitity.It will be stored in form of array.

And if your requirement is different You can use loop.